# arrays vs key value pairs (Map/Object) in React

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, ecmascript-6

I am often torn on wether or not should I be using a key value pair data structure or an array in React when representing a collection of uniquely identifiable objects.

For example, say we would like a component to receive a collection of messages. Is there anything wrong with modeling them like this,

```
{
 message1: {from:"bill" , to:"frank"}, 
 message2: {from:"Jill" , to:"sammy"}
}
```

or similarly as an ES6 `map`, should we use an array of objects like this

```
[
 {name:"message1" , from:"bill" , to:"frank"}, 
 {name:"message2" , from:"Jill" , to:"sammy"}
]
```

I would like to know if there is some kind of best practice regarding the use of key value data structures in React.

Comment: It depends on the operation you are performing. Do you look up objects by id? Use a map. Are you iterating over the objects a lot? Use a list. Doing both? Use both!

Comment: How would you do both? You would need to synchronize their states, and have duplicate data.

Comment: Objects are represented as reference. So something like this works as expected: `var map = {foo: {}, bar: {}}; var list = [map.foo, map.bar]; map.foo.baz = 42; console.log(list[0].baz);`. Both the map and the list have references to the same objects.

Comment: Would we not just use Map if we are iterating because it is iterable?

Comment: If you don't have to perform any other operations such as filtering or sorting, then yes, using just a `Map` would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's better to use objects, even if it's more easier to list/map through the data when using arrays, in most cases you'll want to edit specific elements and an object with the identifier as key will help a lot.

This provides some useful details:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJxcVidE0I0&t=415s